# Perl pack, unpack and STDIN

Tags: perl, stdin, pack, unpack

Can someone explains me why this is not working as I expect it?

```
zen:~ emx$ echo ABC | perl -nle "print unpack 'H*'"
414243
zen:~ emx$ echo 414243 | perl -nle "print pack 'H*'"

zen:~ emx$
```

Somehow I was expecting the second command to print ABC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unpack()` uses `$_` by default if you do not provide it with a second parameter; [`pack()` on the other hand, does not](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).

Comment: But `echo 414243 | perl -nle "print pack 'H*', $_"` also produces no result.

Comment: That would be because your shell is expanding the `$_` variable to nothing before perl had any chance to see it. You want `echo 414243 | perl -nle "print pack 'H*', \$_"`

Comment: Ouch the beginner's mistake! Thanks for pointing it out. `echo 414243 | perl -nle 'print pack "H*", $_'` works great indeed.